# Adjust icon colors based on the background's color

Tags: ios, swift, reactjs, react-native

I have a developer working on an app. The app is built in React Native. I asked if is possible to adjust the colour of some icons depending on the image below:

- Detect the background color/average color/average tone? If the background image is darker, make the icons white
- Detect the background color/average color/average tone? If the background image is lighter, make the icons black

I have received the answer that it is not possible, even tho' I have read some time ago that it could be done in Swift and even in React if compiled in xCode. My code knowledge is limited and I have no code to offer. I would like to know only if it's possible or not to achieve such feature in React Native.

Comment: do you have 2 sets of the same icon and do you know the background color of the image or are you expecting the app to detect the color of background image?

Comment: This is quite possible, you would just need to keep track of the background with some booleans and apply simple logic on the icons.

Comment: @GauravRoy I have two sets of icons. I don't know the background color, that should be somehow detected. I have updated the initial question. Please check the dotted list.

Comment: okay, i've never tried this , but i think if you detect the color from backend it would be great coz RN is a bit rigid and currently it doenst provide any color picker from image. Do check this out https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-color-picker

Comment: @GauravRoy thank you for the suggestion. please post this comment so I can mark it as the answer.

Comment: @Darkkz posted :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay, i've never tried this , but i think if you detect the color from backend it would be great coz RN is a bit rigid and currently it doenst provide any color picker from image. Do check this out npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-color-picker